# Getting returnDistinctValues functionality from 10.1 in ArcGIS Server 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

It is possible to get returnDistinctValues functionality from AGS 10.1 in AGS 10.0?

From ArcGIS Server REST API:

```
 New in 10.1 SP1

Support for a new parameter called returnDistinctValues
that accepts a boolean value was added. When true query 
result would contain distinct values
based on the fields specified in outFields parameter.
```

Maybe someone knows some smart query?

Comment: You  could always write your own query in a servlet, or write an SOE, but AGS 10.0 has been retired for nearly eight months.  If you upgrade, you'll get *all* the new functionality, without having to spend a month customizing ancient software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @Vince:

> You  could always write your own query in a servlet, or write an SOE [Server Object Extension],
>   but [ArcGIS Server] 10.0 has been retired for nearly eight months.  If you
>   upgrade, you'll get *all* the new functionality, without having to
>   spend a month customizing ancient software.